# Split with pandas dataframe column duplicate values into two dataframes, one with duplicate, one without duplicate

Tags: python, numpy

eg.

INPUT: one dataframe

```
   Name     id     Price
   Apple     01       13.86
   Cherry    02       13.24
   Banana    02       1.99
   Peach     03       14.76
   Orange    04       2.48
```

OUTPUT:  two dataframes

one with with duplicate dataframe[id]:

```
   Name     id     Price
   Cherry    02       13.24
   Banana    02       1.99
```

other without duplicate dataframe[id]:

```
   Name     id     Price
   Apple     01       13.86
   Peach     03       14.76
   Orange    04       2.48
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INPUT: df;
OUTPUT: df_duplicated, df_unique

```
df_duplicated = df[df['id'].duplicated(keep=False)]
df_unique = pd.concat([df, df_duplicated]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

print(df_duplicated)
print(df_unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
noDuplicate = data.drop_duplicates('id', keep=False)
print("No Duplicates:", noDuplicate)

duplicate = data[data['id'].duplicated(keep=False)]
print("Duplicates:", duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrence of each unique identifier and then merge the result on your dataframe to get the unique and duplicate values.

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]})
agg_df = df.groupby(by='Id').agg(count=('Id', 'count'))
agg_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
filtered_df = agg_df.loc[agg_df['count'] == 1].merge(df, on=['Id'])
unique_df = agg_df.loc[agg_df['count'] > 1].merge(df, on=['Id'])
```